# Mathematica plot showing discontinuities

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to make some simple plots for my semiconductor physics class and the results are showing some strange discontinuties.

Here is the code:

```
EAminusEV = 0.067;
NA = 10^16;
ND = 10^14;
k = 1.381*10^-23;
gA = 4;
m0 = 9.11*10^-31;
mp = 0.81*m0;
h = 6.626*10^-34;
keV = 8.617*10^-5;

Nv[x_] = 2 ((2 \[Pi] mp k)/(h^2 x))^1.5*10^-6;
p1[x_] = Nv[x]/gA Exp[EAminusEV/keV x];
pPlus[x_] = (-(ND + p1[x]) + 
   Sqrt[(ND + p1[x])^2 + 4 p1[x] (NA - ND)])/2;
pMinus[x_] = (-(ND + p1[x]) - 
   Sqrt[(ND + p1[x])^2 + 4 p1[x] (NA - ND)])/2;

LogLogPlot[pPlus[x], {x, 1/20, 1/300}, PlotRange -> All]
```

And here is the result:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are being bitten by floating point numbers with large exponents, few digits after the decimal points, Exp[large numbers], etc.  Compare your result with this modification that does everything with exact rational math until the last step where it uses 64 digits of precision.

```
EAminusEV = 0067/1000;
NA = 10^16;
ND = 10^14;
k = 1381/1000*10^-23;
gA = 4;
m0 = 911/100*10^-31;
mp = 081/100*m0;
h = 6626/1000*10^-34;
keV = 8617/1000*10^-5;
Nv[x_] = 2 ((2 \[Pi] mp k)/(h^2 x))^(3/2)*10^-6;
p1[x_] = Nv[x]/gA Exp[EAminusEV/keV x];
pPlus[x_] = (-(ND + p1[x]) + Sqrt[(ND + p1[x])^2 + 4 p1[x] (NA - ND)])/2;
pMinus[x_] = (-(ND + p1[x]) - Sqrt[(ND + p1[x])^2 + 4 p1[x] (NA - ND)])/2;
ListLogLogPlot[Table[{N[x,64], N[pPlus[x],64]}, {x,1/300,1/20,1/10^4}],
  Joined->True, PlotRange->All]
```

[image]

You should note the tiny range on the vertical axis and the magnitudes on that axis. That almost certainly means that you should check carefully to verify that all your input parameters are correct to at least six digits of precision, which seems unlikely considering the form in which you have entered them. If you don't have that then borrow some good expensive recently calibrated instruments with six or seven known digits of precision to make all your measurements. If you don't have that precision for every parameter then this is likely just using high powered exact math to translate uncertainty into graphical meaningless nonsense. Just as a hint, this is what your pPlus[ x ] looks like.

```
1/2 (-100000000000000 + \[Sqrt]((100000000000000 + (2292870847500000000000
Sqrt[6290455] E^(6700000 x/8617) \[Pi]^(3/2) (1/x)^(3/2))/36363385297)^2 +
(90797685561000000000000000000000000000 Sqrt[6290455] E^(6700000 x/8617)
\[Pi]^(3/2) (1/x)^(3/2))/36363385297) - (2292870847500000000000 Sqrt[6290455]
E^(6700000 x/8617) \[Pi]^(3/2) (1/x)^(3/2))/36363385297)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get at this:

```
 pPlus[x_] = (-(ND + p1[x]) + 
       Sqrt[(ND + p1[x])^2 + 4 p1[x] (NA - ND)])/2;
```

expand the quantity in the `Sqrt[]`

```
 pPlus[x_] = (-(ND + p1[x]) +
       Sqrt[ND^2 + 4 NA p1[x] - 2 ND p1[x] + p1[x]^2])/2;
```

`p1^2` is much larger than the other terms, pull it out:

```
 pPlus[x_] = (-(ND + p1[x]) + 
       Sqrt[p1[x]^2] Sqrt[(ND^2 + 4 NA p1[x] - 2 ND p1[x])/p1[x]^2 + 1])/2;
```

series expand the `Sqrt` keep first three terms:

```
 pPlus[x_] = (- NA^2 + NA ND)/p1[x] + NA - ND;
```

now you get the same result as @Bill (without resorting to high precision calculations )

```
 LogLogPlot[pPlus[x], {x, 1/20, 1/300}, PlotRange -> All]
```

-->  exact same plot with range 9.8985 - 9.9 10^15